# Is there a way to get which Log Analytics Workspace an Azure Resource belongs to using Powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-log-analytics, oms

I'm looking for a way to obtain which OMS workspace my APIM Services resource is logging to using PowerShell. I want to then configure my Application Gateway to log to the same workspace.

When I go to "Logs" under the APIM service, it shows all available workspaces in my subscription.

I'm not sure how to get just the workspace that it is logging to.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I've been looking for ways to get the workspace as a property of the resource. So $apim = (Get-AzureRmApiManagement)[0] | gm doesn't display a workspace as a property, so I'm not sure how else to get it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a PowerShell Code errors / functionality issue, but how do I find and match up my AzureRM resources and extract information.

However, since you are here...

If the property is not there, then you are not looking at the correct resource cmdlet / object. I don't have this type of scenario deployed in my sub, so no way to dig at it. Take a look at this

[Workspaces - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces/get)

> URI Parameters Name             In    Required  Type    Description
>   subscriptionId      path  True      string  Gets subscription credentials
>   which uniquely identify Microsoft Azure subscription. The subscription
>   ID forms part of the URI for every service call. resourceGroupName
>   path  True      string  The resource group name of the workspace.
>   workspaceName   path  True      string  Name of the Log Analytics
>   Workspace. api-version      query True      string  Client Api Version.

And use the provided properties to cross reference, specifically the resourceGroupName and or workspaceName.

Comment: My issue is that I don't know the name or the rgn. I'm trying to find with workspace my apim service is logging to. All I know if the apim service information.